# Junit for Spring Boot Rest Controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, mocking, spring-test

How can I write a meaningful Junit for the below RestController in Spring Boot

```
@GetMapping("/api")
    public String m2(String process ) {
        
        if( process.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
        {
            jobs.start();
        } else if(process.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))
        {
            jobs.sendEmail();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***In my opinion*** a well-written unit test should be **concise**, be able to cover most if not all of the code branches, verify side-effects, be **fast**, **reliable**, and **easy to read**.

Assuming you're using *JUnit 5* and *Mockito*, something like this would achieve all of the above:

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class MyControllerTests {

  @Mock
  private Jobs jobs;
  private MyController myController;

  @BeforeEach
  public void setUp() {
    myController = new MyControllerImpl(jobs);
  }

  @Test
  void affirmativeProcessShouldStartJobs() {
    myController.m2("Y");
    verify(jobs).start();
  }

  @Test
  void negativeProcessShouldSendEmail() {
    myController.m2("N");
    verify(jobs).sendEmail();
  }

  //...add more tests here, eg.: what do you expect given null input?

}
```

*P.S.: you can clearly improve the readability of this unit test since you know better than any of us what this code means in your application's context. Also, you should add assertions on the `m2(String)` returned value (which we cannot see from your code snippet).*

If you want to test that the API is actually exposed and can be contacted over HTTP, that would be an ***End-to-End*** test rather than a unit test, and I'd recommend not doing it with JUnit but using something that was built with this kind of ***black-box*** testing in mind such as [Cucumber](https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/10-minute-tutorial/).

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer.Can you let me know what does `    verify(jobs).start();`  means?

Comment: `Mockito.verify(mock).someMethod()` verifies that a `someMethod` of the given `mock` has been invoked exactly once.